# AFNetworking - disk capacity

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, afnetworking, asihttprequest

I have found this for limiting Memory capacity and Disk capacity, but my question is what about after 4 MB Memory Capacity and 20 MB Disk Capacity is full then what to do, manually i have to free or it is automatically free, and if it is free automatically then how is work, if it's reach 20 MB disk capacity then it's completely remove or FIFO/LIFO process is there.

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024    //4 MB 
                                                    diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024    //20 MB
                                                           diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

Please provide your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

Also, take into account that you Could clear the cache by calling the removeAllCachedResponses or removeCachedResponsesForRequest methods:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html